# Eclipse Java Enum indents past the opening bracket. How to make it look more normal?

Tags: java, eclipse, enums, formatting, indentation

Unchecking every option under 'Indentation' in the Eclipse formatter profile editor still shows the example 'UNDEFINED' indented all the way past the opening bracket of the Enum 'MyEnum'. A fresh Eclipse configuration may not do this, but I have to start from the profile of this project. Can someone give me a hint what configuration variable may be causing this obscene level of indentation in enums?

[image: screen capture from eclipse preferences]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the formatter profile editor, take a look at the tab named `Line Wrapping` then click on `enum declaration`. I bet you will see that `Indent on column` is selected as `Indentation policy`. Changing the `Indentation policy` to another value will reduce the amount of indentation. Alternatively you can change the `Line wrapping policy` to `Do not wrap`.

Comment: Thank you. I never would have guessed that line wrapping settings would be relevant.

Comment: if anyone ever finds a sane alternative to the Eclipse formatter, please let me know :(